# Collapse outlines of members of typescript classes

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2013

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> in a c# file collapses all members of all classes in the file but not classes or namespaces.
[image]

Pressing same keys in a typescript collapses all outlines even the namespaces and classes.
[image: collapse outlines of a typescript file]

How can I get same behavior for collapsing a typescript file like a c# file?

- Is there any shortcut or a visual studio extension to achieve my goal?
- Is this behavior become default behavior in earlier versions of visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this behavior become default behavior in earlier versions of visual studio?

I just checked visual studio 2015 and visual studio 2017 and this is now defalt behavior of visual studio when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>

> Is there any shortcut or a visual studio extension to achieve my goal?

As the newer versions of visual studio have the feature out of the box and older versions are going to be abandoned I don't think there is/would be any shortcut or extension for the this propose.

I should try to convince our company to migrate to newer version of VS or spend some of my time to write such an extension.